# twbsPagination plugin Issue

Tags: pagination

I am using twbsPagination, and I am stuck with the issue below.

`onPageClick` event never fires after I destroy and initialize new options like totalpages.

Here is my code:

```
function ShowPages(update, TotalPages) {

        if (update) {

            var $pagination = $('#pagination');
            var defaultOpts = {
                totalPages: 10
            };

            var currentPage = $pagination.twbsPagination('getCurrentPage');
            $pagination.twbsPagination('destroy');
            $pagination.twbsPagination($.extend({}, defaultOpts, {
                startPage: currentPage,
                totalPages: TotalPages,
                first: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140"></i> </span>',
                prev: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-150"></i></i></span>',
                next: '<span>  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-150"></i></i></span>',
                last: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140"></i></span>'
            }));
        }
        else {
            $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: TotalPages,
                visiblePages: 7,
                first: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-left bigger-140"></i> </span>',
                prev: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-left bigger-150"></i></i></span>',
                next: '<span>  <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-right bigger-150"></i></i></span>',
                last: '<span> <i class="ace-icon fa fa-angle-double-right bigger-140"></i></span>',
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                    GetMyTasks(page);
                  }
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `destroy` method totally destroys your plugin, which means your callback on click event also was destroyed (`onPageClick` event). So try to add your callback after destroying plugin. 
For example:

```
    function ShowPages(update, TotalPages) {

        if (update) {
            var $pagination = $('#pagination');
            var currentPage = $pagination.twbsPagination('getCurrentPage');
            $pagination.twbsPagination('destroy');
            renderPagination(currentPage, TotalPages)
        }
        else {
            renderPagination(1, TotalPages)
        }

    }
    function renderPagination(currentPage, totalPages) {
        $('#pagination').twbsPagination({
            startPage: currentPage,
            totalPages: totalPages,
            initiateStartPageClick: false,
            onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                GetMyTasks(page);
            }
        });
    }
```

Be careful with initiateStartPageClick option, by default:

> Fire click at start page when plugin initialized
>   From [Official doc](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/)